# Lambda syntax. How join by 1 to many keys

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, lambda

i'm trying rewrite query from native sql to l**inq lambda syntax** (not *linq query syntax*)

**LINQ** (not work)

```
 var result = _uow.Repository<TableA>().Get().AsNoTracking()
    .GroupJoin(
        _uow.Repository<TableB>().Get().AsNoTracking(),
        a => new { a.TabNotesCodeId, a.TabLabelCodeId },
        b => b.ElementNameId
        (b, a) => new SubSection
        {
            SubSectionName = b.CustomValue ?? a.TabLabelCodeId,
            SubSectionNote = b.CustomValue ?? a.TabLabelCodeId,
        })
    .Where(a => a.ResourceId == 1);
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT [SubSectionName] = ISNULL(B.CUSTOMVALUE,A.TABLABELCODEID),
       [SubSectionNote] = ISNULL(B.CUSTOMVALUE,A.TABNOTESCODEID)
FROM TableA as A LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT CUSTOMVALUE, ELEMENTNAMEID FROM TableB WHERE DISPLAYSETTINGID = 1) as B
        ON B.ELEMENTNAMEID IN ( A.TABNOTESCODEID, A.TABLABELCODEID)
WHERE A.RESOURCEID = 1
```

**Q** How to *rewrite* sql **ON B.ELEMENTNAMEID IN ( A.TABNOTESCODEID, A.TABLABELCODEID)** to **lambda syntax**

```
...
  a => new { a.TabNotesCodeId, a.TabLabelCodeId },
  b => b.ElementNameId
....
```

(doesn't work)

Comment: Normally it is : GroupBy(x => new {value = x.CustomValue, id = x.TabelCodeId})

Comment: I think group operation will have different result than join operation. 
there is not any logic about Aggregation

Comment: Look at msdn.  I think you want Left Outer Join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: `x IN (A, B)` is just a SQL trick for doing `OR`: (x = A) OR (x = B)` so you can do the same in LINQ, but not with a `GroupJoin` - LINQ only supports equi-join, so you have to do a cross-product then `Where` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless experiments i've found out solution:

```
                    _uow.Repository<TableA>().Get().AsNoTracking()
                    .GroupJoin(
                        _uow.Repository<TableB>().Get().AsNoTracking().Where(b => b.DisplaySettingId == 1),
                        a => new { note = a.TabNotesCodeId, label = a.TabLabelCodeId },
                        b => new { note = b.ElementNameId, label = b.ElementNameId },
                        (a, b) => new { a,b })
                    .Where(joinTables => joinTables.a.ResourceId == 1)
                    .SelectMany(
                        joinTables => joinTables.b.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                        (joinTables, b) => new SubSection()
                        {
                            LayoutTab = joinTables.a.LayoutTab,
                            SubSectionName = b.CustomValue ?? joinTables.a.TabLabelCodeId,
                            SubSectionNote = b.CustomValue ?? joinTables.a.TabNotesCodeId
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would suggest following my SQL conversion rules, but this is sufficiently complex I don't think it would help.

To use query comprehension syntax on a non-equijoin that is a left join, it seems easiest to use lambda syntax to express the join conditions, so I just combined the sub-query with the join conditions:

```
var ans = from A in TableA
          where A.ResourceID == 1
          from B in TableB.Where(b => b.DisplaySettingID == 1).Where(b => b.ElementNameID == A.TabNotesCodeID || b.ElementNameID == A.TabLabelCodeID).DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new {
              SubSectionName = (B.CustomValue ?? A.TabLabelCodeID),
              SubSectionNote = (B.CustomValue ?? A.TabNotesCodeID)
          };
```

The lambda equivalent of multiple `from` clauses to generate a cross join is `SelectMany`, so converting into lambda syntax:

```
var ans2 = TableA.Where(a => a.ResourceID == 1)
                 .SelectMany(a => TableB.Where(b => b.DisplaySettingID == 1).Where(b => b.ElementNameID == a.TabNotesCodeID || b.ElementNameID == a.TabLabelCodeID)
                                        .DefaultIfEmpty(),
                                        (a, b) => new {
                                            SubSectionName = (b.CustomValue ?? a.TabLabelCodeID),
                                            SubSectionNote = (b.CustomValue ?? a.TabNotesCodeID)
                                        }
                            );
```